# Add and Remove class to child and parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

when i click on 'customer-row' it should add class 'open-carrier-tiers' in 'carrier-tiers'. which is working.
but when i click on 'carrier-tiers-close-btn' then it should remove the same class that added before from its parent parent element. which is not working.
and i am using $(this) because this whole code repeating multiple time on page.

```
<tr class="customer-row">
  <td class="carrier-tiers">
    <div class="content-box">
      <li class="carrier-tiers-close-btn">close</li>
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="Customer Name">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(".customer-row").click(function () {
    $(this).find("td.carrier-tiers").addClass('open-carrier-tiers');
});

$(".carrier-tiers-close-btn").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open-carrier-tiers');
});
```

Comment: does this raise any errors or messages when you click?  Check that the event is actually registered by using a basic "console.log("clicked")" style debug. Can you provide more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the close event is being fired whenever the row is clicked because the event bubbles up. To fix this add an [event.stopPropation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to the event handler. This will prevent the row click from also firing close. Try the code snippet below to see if it works for you.

```js
$(".customer-row").click(function(e) {
  $(this).find("td.carrier-tiers").addClass('open-carrier-tiers')
  e.stopPropagation();

  console.log(document.querySelector("td.carrier-tiers").className);

});

$(".carrier-tiers-close-btn").click(function(e) {
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open-carrier-tiers');
  e.stopPropagation();

  console.log(document.querySelector(".carrier-tiers-close-btn").className);

});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="customer-row">
      <td>customer-row</td>
      <td class="carrier-tiers">
        <div class="content-box">
          <li class="carrier-tiers-close-btn">close</li>
          <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="Customer Name">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using more precise selectors.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".customer-row td:eq(0)").click(function() {
    $(this).next("td.carrier-tiers").addClass('open-carrier-tiers');
  });
  $(".carrier-tiers-close-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.open-carrier-tiers').removeClass('open-carrier-tiers');
  });
});
```

```css
.open-carrier-tiers {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="customer-row">
      <td>customer-row</td>
      <td class="carrier-tiers">
        <div class="content-box">
          <ul>
            <li class="carrier-tiers-close-btn">close</li>
          </ul>
          <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="Customer Name">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you targeted the Row, the click event on the child could not bubble up.